# How may i execute just 1 iteration when the condition is met?

Tags: python, time, python-2.7, iteration

I am using while true loop to produce an infinite loop. And, in the code, i have a section which is dependent on time. Here's the code:

```
while True:
    if currentminute == '53':
        # do this
    else:
        # do that
```

How may I make it just execute one loop of the 'do this' code if currentminute == '53' is true? And, execute 'do that' code which represents the bulk of all the other codes for the rest of the hour and come back to 'do this' code the next hour, etc.

Comment: Please format your code properly, especially if it's Python.

Comment: You could do something like import the `datetime` module (or `time`) and have your `if` statement read `if datetime.datetime.now().minute == 53: <your_code>`. However I'm not sure I completely understand the question, so this may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm not a python programmer but it looks like you don't need the first line (`while True:`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
while True:
    if datetime.datetime.now().minute == 53:
        # do this
        if datetime.datetime.now().minute == 53:  # if still 53 then sleep for rest of the seconds
            time.sleep(60-datetime.datetime.now().second)
    else:
        # do that
```

From your question, I assume that *only* the `#do this` part should be executed *only once* every 53 minute. Also you need to make sure that `#do that` part doesn't hold the execution for long so that it could overlap the 53rd minute.